# Conditionally show fields on Ruby on Rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app using Bootstrap for styling.  This is a snippet from a form and I want to make a field visible once the non-blank value from the previous field is selected.  Thus, once non-blank 'criteria' is selected, I want to make the 'criteria_reason' field visible.  How can this code be fixed?

```
<%= f.select :criteria, ['', 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'] %>

<%= f.text_field :criteria_reason, class:"form-control", placeholder:'Reason',
      style:"#{'display:none' if :criteria == ''}" %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use javascript to make it visible on invisible when you click drop-down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#category_category_id").change(function () {
        var category = $(this).val();
        if (category != "") {
          $("#category_criteria_reason").show();
        } else {
          $("#category_criteria_reason").hide();
        }
    });

  });
</script>
```

change `category_` with you own form class. Then, you can change you default code into

```
<%= f.text_field :criteria_reason, class:"form-control", placeholder:'Reason',
      style:"#{'display:none' if f.object.criteria == ''}" %>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't use any class for the form. And there are 50 or so pairs of fields that need to have this functionality.  Can you please suggest how to tweak your code to accommodate that?  Thansk

Comment: In my code, I have form like `<%= form_for(@category, url: admin_categories_url, html: {method:'post', multipart: true}) do |f| %>` so my class form is `category`. Then, You have to change your prefix `id` into your class form in javascript code. For example: if your class `post`, you can change into `$("#post_criteria_reason")` in you javascript. Last, put your javascript in below of your form. I hope it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

by calling `form_for @object do |f|` you are passing `@object` into a `ActionView::FormBuilder`. In `f` you can access the related object by calling `f.object`

so in this case you need to do

```
<%= f.text_field :criteria_reason, class:"form-control", placeholder:'Reason',
      style:"#{'display:none' if f.object.criteria == ''}" %>
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting.  This works after I submit the form. However, I need the field to hide based on the previous selection **before** the form is submitted.